# как вывести нужную запись по id из БД

Tags: php, mysql

есть БД news из которой на индексной странице выводится заголовок и анонс новости. С помощью ссылки, через id осуществляется переход на страницу полной статьей.
Не получается вывести на новую страницу статью, так, чтобы по id статья совпадала с заголовком и анонсом.

код индексной страницы прилагаю

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<a href="view.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title']. '</a>';
    echo $data['announce']. '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Не со всем разобрался, но судя по названию: SELECT * FROM news WHERE `id`='123'

Comment: `SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=123` - кавычки для числовых значений не используются

Answer (score 1):

Сам по себе код получения записи по id очень простой. Всего три строчки.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?"; 
$result = $db->execute_query($sql, [$id]); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

в `$row` будет данные запрошенной строки, если она существует.

Если у вас устаревшая версия РНР, то временную замену для метода `execute_query()` можно взять [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple#shim)

Кроме того, всегда желательно валидировать входящую информацию, и не выполнять запрос, если для него заведомо нет подходящих данных. Это можно сделать так:

```
// проверка и получение id из строки запроса
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    die(http_response_code(404));
}

$id = $_GET['id']; 
// проверка на число
if (!ctype_digit($id)) {
    die(http_response_code(400));
}

// выполнение запроса
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?"; 
$result = $db->execute_query($sql, [$id]); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Ну и не забыть правильный код подключения к mysql, который длжен быть в отдельном файле

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

вместо 'host', 'username', 'password', 'database_name' указать свои параметры подключения к БД

Answer (score -1):

1. Не пишите код PHP прям посреди HTML, весь код как минимум должен исполняться перед выводом HTML.
2. Не используйте экранирование `@` - лучше проверяйте наличие параметра через `isset`, если `$_GET['page']` нет, тогда записи выводятся с первой страницы.
3. Никогда не пишите HTML в PHP переменных, или старайтесь избегать по максимуму.
4. Каким образом Вы пытались открыть страницу с конкретной новостью? Кода для этого у Вас нет, если вкратце, то Вы должны получить `$_GET['id']`, сказать ему `$id=(int)$_GET['id']`, а потом уже искать новость по `$id`, если что-то найдено, то выводим, если нет, то говорим извините, мол, ошиблись вы, батенька.

Answer (score -2):

на новой странице пишешь запрос:

```
"SELECT * FROM news WHERE idate=".$_GET['id_news'];
```

где $_GET['id_news'] идентификатор новости из URL,

дальше выводи новость на странице известным уже путем

P.S. переходи на PDO